# How can I convert a Perforce task stream to a development stream?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

It says on several places in the Perforce documentation that it is possible to convert a task stream to a development stream, but I did not find how to actually do it.

In P4V, when I right-click a stream in the Stream view and choose Edit stream 'X', there's the Stream type combobox where I think I am supposed to change the 'task' option to 'development'.  For development streams, I can use the combobox to convert the stream to for example a mainline or virtual stream, but for all my tasks streams, the combobox is disabled.

How can I convert the task stream to a development stream? Is there some prerequisite condition that I have to fulfill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry that you are having issues converting your task stream. In our docs under the section 'Convert a task stream to a regular stream' it mentions:

```
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/streams_task.html

   Convert a task stream to a regular stream

Important! Once you convert a task stream to a regular stream, you cannot convert it back.

To convert a task stream to a regular stream:

    1. Context-click the task stream in the Streams tab and select Edit Stream 'stream_name'.
    2. Change the Stream type to the regular stream type you want.
        -- Task streams with parents can convert only to release or development streams.
        -- A parentless task stream can convert only to a mainline stream.
        -- You cannot convert a task stream to a virtual stream.
    3. Verify that the parent stream (if there is one) is in the same depot as the task stream to be converted.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The point 3 is what prevents my stream from being converted, because my task stream is in a 'tasks' depot.